# Is there a way to adjust <input type="label">?

Tags: html, css, styles

Just want to change the input type from text to label so it don't display like it can be edited. Is there a way?

For example I have an input tag here

```
<td><input class='edit' type = 'text' style="height:90px;" name="ID[]" value='<?php echo 
$row['ID']; ?>' maxlength="50" readonly="readonly"/></td>
```

Now it's not editable but it looks like a textbox, how can i change it to label type of look?

Comment: is there an input type = "label" !! ?

Comment: ya, is there an input type = label?

Comment: there is only a <label> tag. Do you mean that ?

Comment: You should reformulate the question, including its title, which is now very misleading. My guess is that you want to *display* an `<input type=text>` element so that it looks like label. For this, you need to explain what you mean by “label type of look” (perhaps with a reference to an image of such a look) and show your best effort at that.

Comment: Perhaps what you *really* want would best be achieved using an `<input type=hidden>` field, possibly along with normal text content that shows the (unchangeable) value to the user.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for [`<label>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label), or are you simply trying to add some CSS to make your `readonly` input look less like an input area?

```
input[readonly]
{
    border: none;
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Marty if you are willing to use input only,
else you can try property disabled, that will also make input read only.

else
Why don't you try `<div>` ?

```
<td>
  <div class='edit' style="height:90px;width:120px" name="ID[]">
    <?php echo $row['ID']; ?>
  </div>
</td>
```

this div will make the page lighter and more speedy and easy to customize too.